# sql stored procedure paramater single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

below is the stored procedure

```
create procedure testpro
@screen varchar(10)
as
begin
declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = 'SELECT * FROM
--
--{code}
--

WHERE SCREEN_NAME = ' + @SCREENNAME + ' AND  Ord=3 ORDER BY date DESC'
```

here SCREEN_NAME = 'Normal' should be the input but in the above my procedure the query is giving input as SCREEN_NAME = Normal so its showing error since screen name is varchar.. 
how to give the parameter in the above code with single parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Just remove single quote `''` from your query..

```
set @query = 'SELECT * FROM' 
{ Code Here }
@query = @query +' WHERE SCREEN_NAME = ''' + @SCREENNAME + ''' And Ord=3  Order By date Desc'
```

Comment: please see my question again i have edited it and give solution

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to wrap parameter in quotes `''`. So simply remove quotes and use

```
WHERE SCREEN_NAME = @SCREENNAME  ORDER BY date DESC
```

### EDIT

You need to escape `'`, I have not tested it

Use

```
 WHERE SCREEN_NAME = ''' + @SCREENNAME + ''' AND  Ord=3 ORDER BY date DESC'
```

Comment: please see my question again i have edited it and give solution